Is it possible to invalidate Vercel edge cache?
We have a next.js pages application deployed on Vercel and we want to invalidate Vercel Edge cache. A few important things:

We're currently using the "Pages" router.
We can't change the URL (i.e ?v=2.2)

I saw that in App Router there is the revalidatePath but it doesn't work for Pages router.
We basically want to be able to invalidate the cache without re-entering the website.
I saw CloudFront has this feature
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=S11A16G5KZMEQD --paths /

But we can't use CloudFront at the moment
Do you know if there is any way to invalidate the pages cache somehow?
Thanks!
